# Show outdated gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

To avoid crashing anything I specify the version number for every gem in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 1.0.3'
gem 'haml-rails', "~> 0.3.4"
gem 'simple_form', '~> 1.5.2'
```

But I want to, at least, know if there are some newer version I haven’t installed. For instance, `simple_form 2.0.0` has been released.

I can check each gem on RubyGems, but there must be a automatic tool to do this chore, right?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With the latest version (1.1) of [bundler](http://getbundler.com) you can do `bundle outdated` ([see this page.](http://gembundler.com/v1.1/bundle_outdated.html))

To update bundler to the latest version you can run `gem update bundler`

```
gazler@gazler-laptop:~/development/rails/livestax$ bundle outdated
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..

Outdated gems included in the bundle:
  * multi_json (1.2.0 > 1.0.3)
  * activesupport (3.2.3 > 3.1.0)
  * activemodel (3.2.3 > 3.1.0)
  * rack (1.4.1 > 1.3.5)
  * rack-cache (1.2 > 1.0.3)
  * sprockets (2.4.0 > 2.0.3)
  * actionpack (3.2.3 > 3.1.0)
  * mime-types (1.18 > 1.17.2)
```

There is also the [Gemnasium](https://gemnasium.com/) but I have never used it.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Gazler, you can use bundle outdated to see the newest gem available. You can also use a service like SourceNinja (www.sourceninja.com) that will send you email notifications when newer gems are available.

Disclosure: I work at SourceNinja.

Answer (score 1):

`bundle outdated` will do the job. But that's not automated. If you want to automate the process you should use [VersionEye](https://www.versioneye.com/). [VersionEye](https://www.versioneye.com/) can monitor your Gemfile on GitHub or Bitbucket and notifies you about out-dated dependencies in your project via email.

By the way. I'm the dude who started VersionEye.